Is it possible to parse odata query from uri sql raw?
Here is example odata uri:
https://web.com.pl/api/ControlerName?$filter=(Sn%20eq%2011223344%20and%20Id%20in%20(1,2,3)%20and%20Time%20ge%202024-03-23T22:00:00.000Z%20and%20Time%20lt%202024-04-24T19:00:59.999Z)&$orderby=Time%20asc&$count=true&$top=20&$skip=0
Is there any library that will allow to parse the data query sent this way into SQL RAW? Without having an EDM model, just using the names included in the filters?
Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);
It will separate individual $filter, $select, $count etc.
But is there any way to get the string
SN = 112233 and ID in (1,2,3) and Time >= ... and Time < .... order by Time asc
I found something like this: https://github.com/IharYakimush/comminity-data-odata-linq
But it doesn't support "IN".
